# Getting started with handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm hacking around Handlebars for the first time; my goal is to display a list of items in the html.

This is the script inside the html:

```
<div>
  <script id="list-items" type="text/x-handlebars-template">​
    {{#each list}} {{ price }} {{/each}}
  </script>
</div>
```

This is the js file:

```
var list = [
          {
            name: 'Almond Toe Court Shoes, PatentBlack',
            category: 'Women\'s footwear',
            price: 42,
            quantity: 5
          },
          {
            name: 'Bla bla bla',
            category: 'Women\'s footwear',
            price: 66,
            quantity: 5
          }
        ];

     var theTemplateScript = $("#list-items").html();          

     var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile (theTemplateScript);
          
     $(document.body).append (theTemplate (list));
```

My code doesn't work and I see no errors in the console.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your template iterates over a `list` attribute but you pass the raw array.

To reconcile your template and the data you pass, either pass an object with a `list` attribute :

```
$(document.body).append (theTemplate ({
    list: list
}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/hm6psg9w/1/

or modify your template to iterate over an array:

```
<script id="list-items" type="text/x-handlebars-template">​
    {{#each .}} {{ price }} {{/each}}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/hm6psg9w/